# by-value return in functions of c++

Tags: c++, pass-by-value

is this code correct in c++?

```
list<int> makelist(int litem)
{
    list<int> newList;
    newList.push_front(litem);
    return newList;
}
```

should it make problems to return a list (of `#include <list>`) by value?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: There is no problem with doing this, ths problem is with returning a pointer or a reference to a local object that will go away. This will copy the list, or at least act as if it has

Comment: How can we know whether this is correct when we don't know your `list` type?

Comment: I have no idea what "a list of #include" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @sbi: Should not matter what the type is. The code should work whatever the type is (unless there is a bug in the type being returned but that is not the problem of makelist()).

Comment: @tomer: (You need to explicitly @address people in comment replies, so that your replies show up in their Responses tab.) In that case it's spelled `std::list`. Writing this out would have made your posting only 10 characters longer, but be much clearer.

Comment: @Karl: It means tomer hadn't formatted his posting correctly. (Un-escaped `<` and `>` are apparently interpreted as tags.)

Comment: @Martin: What if it was (something similar to) `std::auto_ptr<>`?

Comment: @sbi: Now you are going for the edges of reality. But it still works (As it should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, returning by values will normally be optimized away (when running with optimization turned on). So if speed is the concern (which it shouldn't until it has been proven by a profiler) you shouldn't worry. If list on the other hand has some strange side effects when copying you should be aware of the number of copy constructor calls will vary depending on compiler and settings.

Answer (score 1):

It'll work, but it's not efficient, because a lot of memory might be copied. In the next C++ standard, this problem can be solved. 
I'd suggest the following code:

```
void fillList(list & lst) {
   lst.push_front(...);
}
....
list newList;
fillList(newList);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is inefficient? As far as I understood, C++ optimizer care about it and doesn't do any memory copy! Oh, seems I am right, read @nice_blonde_stupid_girl's comment above.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't do this, _unless profiling has shown this is a bottleneck_. Likely return value optimization will take care of this, and even if not, such optimizations should be reserved to when they are _needed_, rather than being applied prematurely.

Answer (score -1):

You can't return a local object that aren't a simply type (int, float, char), but you can return a pointer to a new object:

```
list<int>* makelist(int litem)
{
    list<int>* newList = new list<int>();
    newList->push_front(litem);
    return newList;
}
```

take care that you MUST manage the pointer latter to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: That's plain wrong. The only types you cannot return per copy are those that prevent copying.

Comment: I am sorry, but c++ has no problem with returning any local object by value as long as they are copyable in one way or another. No pointers are needed. This answer is simply wrong.